# Question about proof of pseudo-random random generators being one way functions

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, one-way-function, adversarial-model

I've been looking over this proposition and proof in the book "Introduction to modern cryptography" and am a little confused. Picture is attached at the bottom).

Why is it that we do not multiply the $2^{-n}$ by $\varepsilon$.

It is true that the probability of being in the generator range is $2^{-n}$ but even once we're there the chances of A giving the correct inverse are not $1$.

Should the equation not be $\leq  \varepsilon ~ 2^{-n}$ instead?

[image]

Comment: We don't multiply by epsilon because it is not necessary; the argument is fine as it is.

Comment: That much is clear... My question is why is it not necessary?

Comment: Because the argument is correct without it. Or do you see a flaw?

Comment: Yes I do. Like I said, they claim that we take that value because that's the probability of w being in the range. But even if it is in the range we still run w through A and depending on what it replies we make our choice. And A guesses correctly with probability epsilon.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. A flaw in a mathematical argument is a statement that is false, or at least sufficiently lacking in justification that a competent reader would find its truth dubious. Do you see such a statement in the text? If so, quote it exactly. You have several highlighted parts in your question.

Comment: I'm sure it's all correct. I want to know why. Why does it not work like I said?
I told you what I expect to see. I simply want to know why it is not correct to take into account the probability of A being correct. Say that w really is in the range of G, fine, the next step of the algorithm is to feed w into A get x, check G(x)=w and return 1 if it's true. But A only answers correctly with probability epsilon. Where is that taken into account in the given proof?
It is still possible to return 0 even if w is in the range, that is what this boils down to for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's analyzed in this way because it is tricky to correctly conclude much more than what's written here.  The issue is that a uniformly random string $w$ in the image of $G$ is *not* necessarily distributed like $G(x)$ for a uniformly random $x$. We know that $\mathcal{A}(y)$ succeeds with $\varepsilon$ probability for a random input $y=G(x)$ of the latter form, but that doesn't tell us much about how it behaves in the former case.

More precisely, conditioned on $w$ being in the image of $G$, it is uniformly random in that image.  This does *not* necessarily imply that $\mathcal{A}(w)$ ouputs an element of the preimage set $G^{-1}(w) = \{x : G(x)=w\}$ with probability $\varepsilon$.  For example, $G$ could be highly "irregular," meaning that some preimage sets are much larger than others.  But $\mathcal{A}$ might only successfully invert on, say, those $y$ that have very large preimage sets.  This would give it good inverting probability on $y=G(x)$ for uniformly random $x$, but its probability of inverting on a uniform $w$ in the image of $G$ would be much less than $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the case here is simply that they chose to not give a very tight bound. 
What they say is that at most the probability is ${2^{-n}}$. That is that even for a perfect A, one that is right all the time, the probability cannot go above that value. that's why the do not multiply by ${\epsilon}$.

I assume this choice is made for the sake of some other proof further down the line, or maybe just some convention.